# custom attachment field in List

Tags: 2010, list, attachments

I would like to know, can I create a custom attachment field in a list. I know I already have one attachemnt field in the list, how ever I would like to have one more field, where I can attach files in the list...

Is that possible in sharepoint 2010.

Comment: The attachment field allow to attach multiple files.Any special reason you want to do this?

Comment: Amit, we want to show the doc type in one attachment column and ppt type in another attachment column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading your question, I would solve your problem by creating one document library. Name it for example "Attachements". Then add multiple lookup columns in the first list to this new created "Attachements" document library. Important is to set "Select multiple values"

Then the users just needs to add the files to the document library and then create/edit the listitem to select the correct attachements...