# Attachment column

Tags: list

I want to create a column in custom list 'attachment' which should have same behaviour as its name.This field also need to be shown in list view.Do I need to write custom action for the same? I do not want to use existing 'attachment' of list which is in ribbon and do not want to use infopath.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23580/custom-attachment-field-in-list .. you can do something like this

Comment: I tried this but now working , can you please elaborate deeply, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a document library, where you can upload your documents. In your custom list create a column by name **'Attachment'** of type **lookup**.Provide the document library created then as the lookup list and title of document library as lookup field. Reference from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23580/custom-attachment-field-in-list)

Comment: Do not where I am doing wrong but its not working on my end.
I have created document lib and added test file , now created attachment column in list as lookup and linked with created doc lib and selected 'title' , also checked allow multiple. But when i create new item in list 'attachment' field is blank , it should show test file

Comment: Attachment field will be a dropdown where you have to select the files to be linked to this item  and then save

Comment: I am not getting that field in my newform.aspx , only able to see in edit.aspx

Comment: Are you using content types for the list?

Comment: No I am not using any other content type , just default content type 'item' is in use.
just did above procedure but while adding item in same list i am not able to see attachment field in newform.aspx

Comment: It appears for me. I didnt do anything else

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11905/discussion-between-jinxed-and-user21081)

Comment: Did the above solution help?